# Why can't I use System.Management.Automation in ASP.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, namespaces

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, .NET Framework 6 version and I'm trying to use the PowerShell class.

When I start a new console application project I can use `System.Management.Automation` but when I start the default ASP.NET Web app project (razor pages) it says:

> The type or namespace name 'Management' does not exist in namespace
> System

Comment: I have add C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0\System.Management.Automation.dll for referance and started application without any error.

Comment: @KurtısKalacs good coding